# for loop to raw database in the django view

Tags: django

I trying to query raw database, so far working good in django shell but I unable list all records in template. In template show only the last record.

Here my  function in views.py

```
def platformslist(request):
    for platform in Platforms.objects.db_manager('nocdb').raw(
        'SELECT * FROM lu_platform'):
        platform
    print(platform.name) # this is only for verified if working correctly in console
    return render_to_response('platforms.html', {'platform': platform}, 
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

template:

```
<div class="col-md-13">
      <tr> 
          {{ platform.name }}
          {{ platform.prefix }}
      </tr>
```

and my models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.query import RawQuerySet

class Platforms(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    prefix = models.CharField()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass not only the last platform to the template, but all platforms:

```
def platformslist(request):
    platforms = Platforms.objects.db_manager('nocdb').raw(
        'SELECT * FROM lu_platform')
    return render_to_response('platforms.html', {'platforms': platforms}, 
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

then you can loop over the platforms in the template:

```
{% for platform in platforms %}
    {{ platform.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you @sk1p, this working for me now. I already tried this way before but I thing I not cleaned my browser cache.